# Why is synchronous module loading in javascript that bad

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

I know that the synchronous ajax calls on the main thread are deprecated, but I still wonder why.

How do you archive this in asynchronous module loading: `get('moduleDependency').foo();` ?

I would like to use this kind of synchronous calls at least in development to speed up the overall development circle. The modules are in production already concatenated into one file and will never touch the synchronous loading function at all.

My synchronous module loader (~80 loc) solves dependencies and more. I rewrote it to asynchronous loading, and it's working fine... but I'll have to give up using code like: `get('moduleDependencie').foo();`

And that's really a mess!

How do you get this kind of calls working with asynchronous loading? Or do I simply have to use asynchronous loading in cooperation with a `while(true)` function on the main thread in the future - until they ban while loops on the main thread also?

Comment: In general, with promises or callbacks. `get(moduleDependency).then(function(bar) { bar.foo() })`

Comment: This is, for now, the only way to go, I guess.

Instead of using `var module = get('module'); module.foo();` we are eagerly using your solution, without thinking about it for a second.

There has to be a simpler, cleaner way, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the synchronous call isn't finished or a timeout isn't reached, there is no possibility for user to interact with the page. So it can hang up and in worst case the user has to restart his browser. Asynchronous programming and scripting is based on callbacks. You just have to bind a method to the success handler of the AJAX-Request. You can use

```
success:function(result){
//do something
}
```

or

```
success: myfunction
[...]
function myfunction(result){
//do something
}
```

Once the asynchronous code has finished, this method will be called. So put everything that works with the data from the AJAX request into this method.

Comment: Synchronous calls don't provide a timeout at all, only asynchronous calls do. This is not based in the language itself, rather in the unbelievable incapacity of browser vendors to fail to separate the main js-ui-thread from the rest of the browsers main controls. They rather change the standard then changing their babies. And we programmer like complicated, non trivial, unreadable code.